# ggplot axis change total length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to modify my ggplot theme, so that it looks like in the image here:
[image]

I managed to get everything, except the part that the axis are much shorter. I was unable to find any argument in the `element_line` which can control the length of it, but because I think this is not an uncommon thing to do, I must have missed something...

This is the theme so far:

```r
library(ggplot2)

x<-runif(100)
y<-runif(100)
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 10),
        plot.title = element_text(size=13),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "white"),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "white"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour="black", arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"))))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do it with `geom_segment()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=0.2, yend=0), arrow = arrow(length=unit(.5, 'cm')))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=0, yend=0.2), arrow = arrow(length=unit(.5, 'cm')))+
  labs(x = "PHATE1", y = "PHATE2")+
  theme_void()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.1, vjust = 4),
        axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.07, vjust = -4, angle=90)
  )
```

[image]

In case we want closed arrows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=0.2, yend=0), arrow = arrow(length=unit(.5, 'cm'), type = "closed"))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=0, yend=0.2), arrow = arrow(length=unit(.5, 'cm'), type = "closed"))+
  labs(x = "PHATE1", y = "PHATE2")+
  theme_void()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.1, vjust = 4),
        axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.07, vjust = -4, angle=90)
  )
```

[image]

OR using `ggarchery` package:

```
library(ggarchery)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_arrowsegment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=0.2, yend=0), arrows = arrow(type = "closed"))+
  geom_arrowsegment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=0, yend=0.2), arrows = arrow(type = "closed"))+
  labs(x = "PHATE1", y = "PHATE2")+
  theme_void()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.1, vjust = 4),
        axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.07, vjust = -4, angle=90)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer, it was very helpful. Do you have an idea how to "dynamically" place the arrows in the lower left corner? Because the coordinates of the arrows are currently "hardcoded".

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness - it's not difficult to change the length of your axis.

Add limits to `coord_...`, turn clipping off, and add a margin to your plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

x<-runif(100)
y<-runif(100)
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  ## limit the coordinates and turn clipping off
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, .25), ylim = c(0, .25), clip = "off") +
  ## add a margin to your plot
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = 2.6, r = 3.7, unit = "inch"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour="black", arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: One dot in your first quadrant seems to be cut off in the y-axis, is it because of `plot.margin`? If that's the case, how can we ensure none of the points were cut-off even you set `clip = "off"`? Thank you very much for your comment in my answer! +1!

Comment: @benson23 This is the main downside of the above approach - finding the right margin will require some *manual* fine tuning. Luckily, this usually only needs to be done once, as in my experience this type of visualisation will probably be highly customised requirements to one specific figure, thus this approach should be fine. The funny values which I have chosen were based on the data in my session, but using reprex and not having used a seed resulted in modified data, thus the margin here was not quite the right one.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there's no easy way of modifying the length of the ggplot axis. You can completely remove the axis lines and manually add arrows to mimic the axis lines.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  annotate("segment", x = -0.01, xend = 0.2, y = 0, yend = 0, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed")) + 
  annotate("text", x = 0.1, y = -0.05, label = "PHATE 1") +
  annotate("segment", x = -0.01, xend = -0.01, y = 0, yend = 0.2, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed")) + 
  annotate("text", x = -0.05, y = 0.11, label = "PHATE 2", angle = 90) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size=13),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "white"),
        axis.line = element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot_annotate]